# IEnumerable<> being skipped by foreach code; Converting IEnumerable<> to List<> doesnt return anything

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5, windows-8.1

Basically I have this code:

```
public static async Task<bool> SubmitOrdertoBroker(CASOrderModel order, IEnumerable<CASOrderItemModel> modelOrderItems) 
{
      ObservableCollection<CASOrderItem> casOrderItemModel = new ObservableCollection<CASOrderItem>();

      var i = (from m in modelOrderItems select m).ToList();

      foreach (dynamic item in modelOrderItems)
      {
           CASOrderItem orderItem;

           orderItem = new CASOrderItem();
           orderItem.Createdby = item.Createdby;
           orderItem.CreatedDate = item.CreatedDate;
           orderItem.ItemMetaPK = item.ItemMetaPK;
           orderItem.OrderItem = item.OrderItem;
           orderItem.OrderItemID = item.OrderItemID;
           orderItem.ParentOrderID = item.ParentOrderID;
           orderItem.PrdMainPK = item.PrdMainPK;
           orderItem.Quantity = item.Quantity;
           orderItem.TacticPkey = item.TacticPkey;

           casOrderItemModel.Add(orderItem);
      }
      return true;
}
```

The issues are:

1.) The foreach {} block is not iterating, and it just skips the code (even if modelOrderItems has 4 items in it), thereby rendering my casOrderItemModel empty (which I am passing to another code block after this code that supposedly populates the collection).

2.) If I try to convert the IEnumerable to a List, the list doesn't contain any items.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue.

Thank you. :)

Comment: this doesn't make sense. modelOrderItems is probably empty. use `int count = modelOrderItems.Count()` to make sure

Comment: You have a CASOrderModel, CASOrderItemModel, CASOrderItem and a variable named casOrderItemModel that contains CASOrderItem(s), the ones without model in its name. And a parameter called modelOrderItems that contains CASOrderItemModel(s). I'm pretty sure you are just stumbling over you're own naming convention here.

Comment: your " i " variable i never used

Comment: What's the source of the `IEnumerable`? If it's exhaustible then you've exhausted it in `ToList`.

Comment: ironically, modelOrderItems.Count = 4, but when I convert it to list (the variable "i" which is never used but just for testing purposes), i.Count = 0.

Comment: Why the dynamic? Try CASOrderItemModel.  Try var i = new List<CASOrderItemModel>(modelOrderItems)

Comment: Basically?  Post code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `IEnumerable<T>` with `List<T>`. My assumption here is that since it is an interface, there has to be an object that holds your list anywhere in the application.

Comment: Could you explain how that would solve the problem? What would be the difference of changing it to a `List`?

Answer (score 3):

Your function takes a parameter `IEnumerable<CASOrderItemModel> modelOrderItems` on which you call `ToList()`:

```
var i = (from m in modelOrderItems select m).ToList();
```

But then you iterate over `modelOrderItems`, not over `i`:

```
foreach (dynamic item in modelOrderItems) { ... }
```

Evaluating the same enumerable collection twice can result in the second iteration being empty, depending on the source of your collection. Try doing this and remove the unused `ToList()` line:

```
foreach (CASOrderItemModel item in modelOrderItems) { ... }
```

Or if you really want to have that explicit `ToList()` in there:

```
foreach (var item in i) { ... }
```

Finally, since your collection contains a strong typed item `CASOrderItemModel`, using `dynamic` makes no sense.

Comment: that does not explain the i.Count = 0

Comment: You're right. But then judging by the accepted answer, something else completely weird was going on anyway.